# improving small file read times with USB2 attached ext2 volume

Tags: c, linux, performance, ext2

I'm a more experienced Windows programmer than I am a Linux programmer.  Apologies if I'm missing something obvious.

I need to read >10,000 small files (~2->10k) on a USB2 attached ext2 volume running Linux.  The distro is a custom and runs busybox.

I'm hoping for tips on improving these writes.  I'm doing the following

```
handle = open(O_CREAT|O_RDWR)
read(handle, 2kBuffer)
close(handle);
```

since my reads are small, this one read() tends to do the job in one call

Is there anything I can do to improve the performance?  since it's a custom distro of Linux running on a USB2 (removable) disk are there any obvious kernel settings or mount options that I may be missing?

thanks!

Comment: just a workaround idea: is it OK to create one zip/gzip/.. file on the fly which will contain all the files? I'm pretty sure it's going to be faster...

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely recommend opening the file readonly if you only intend to read from it.

Aside from this, have you tried doing several operations in parallel? Does it speed things up? What work are you actually doing with the data read from the files? Does the other work take significant time?

Have you profiled your application?

Answer (score 1):

mount the device with "[atime](http://lwn.net/Articles/244829/)" disabled (you really don't need avery read() call to cause a write of meta data). See the `noatime` mount option. The open() call also takes a  O_NOATIME flag doing the same, on a per file basis.

(Though, many kernels/distros have made the "relatime" option default for some time now, yielding mostly the same speedups)

Answer (score 1):

Since reads from disk are block-sized (and ext* doesn't support block suballocation), if you've simply got a bunch of tiny files that don't come anywhere close to filling a block on their own, you'd be better off bundling them into archives.  This may not be a win if you can't group related files together, though.

Consider ext4?  The `dir_index` option in ext3 is standard in ext4 and speeds up anything with lots of files in the same directory.  It places metadata, directory, and file blocks much more contiguously on disk, and greatly reduces the number of non-data blocks required to track each data block (although that matters more for large files than small).  There's a proposal to inline a small file's data into its inode, but I don't think that's in upstream.

If you're seek-bound (as opposed to bandwidth-bound), it may help to call `fadvise(FADV_WILLNEED)` on a set of files before reading from any of them.  The kernel takes this as a hint to readahead into the file cache.  Do be careful, though: reading ahead more than cache can hold is wasteful and slower.  There's a proposal to add `fincore` to determine when your files have gotten evicted, but I don't think that's upstream yet either.

If it turns out you're bound by bandwidth, having the files compressed with LZO or gzip can help.  The CPU should still be faster decompressing than the disk reads with these compression methods (as opposed to LZMA or bzip2).

Comment: May want to note "[posix_fadvise(WILLNEED) makes IO slower?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936520/posix-fadvisewillneed-makes-io-slower)" as WILLNEED is blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Most distros are horrible about setting their blockio-level caching way too low.  Try setting

`blockdev -setra 8192 /dev/yourdatasdev`

it will use a bit more RAM, but the extra caching works well in just about any situations.  If you have lots of RAM, use bigger values, I am yet to see a downside to this, the throughput and latency just gets better and better with more RAM allocated to it.  There's of course a 'saturation' level, but the stock settings are so low (512) that any improvement tends to have dramatic effects without allocating too much memory for these buffers.

If it is metadata access that slows you down, I like to use a silly trick of putting `updatedb` in crontab, running in short intervals, which keeps the metadata cache warm and preloaded with all the useful info.